# Use of hex value 0x78 when copying data from one location to another

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, boot

Why are we using hex value 0x78 in below given code in the instruction `mov bx,0x78`. A very little code is given below:

```
cli
xor ax,ax
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0x7c00
push ss
pop es
mov bx,0x78  (why we are using 
          hex value 0x78 here)
lds si,ss:bx
push ds
push si
push ss
push bx
mov di,0x7c2b
mov cx,0xb
cld
```

more code here....

Sorry for inconvenience, I have one more problem as mentioned below:

I am working through a very old msdos 1.25 source code and I found an awkward instruction where "$" sign is used as given below. What is $ sign in `mov sp,$0x7c00` ?

I want to know what is the difference between the following two instructions:

```
1. mov sp,$0x7c00
2. mov sp,0x7c00
```

Comment: I thought DOS was written in MASM syntax, which only accepts `7c00h` for hex literals, not `0x7c00`.  What assembler is this for?  (Syntax depends on the assembler, not just the target machine-code format.)

Answer (score 2):

The `mov bx,0x78` instruction loads an offset address in the `BX` register. Because the associated segment register (in casu `SS`) holds zero, the datum that we will address is in the Interrupt Vector Table. It's the `Int 1E` Disk-initialization parameter table.

The `lds si,ss:bx` (better written as `lds si, [ss:bx]`) loads the `SI` register with the offset word found at `SS:BX` and loads the `DS` register with the segment word found at `SS:BX+2`.

Further code will then be copying the 11-byte table to a buffer within the bootloader.

---

> I want to know what is the difference between the following two instructions:

> ```
> 1. mov sp,$0x7c00
> 2. mov sp,0x7c00
> ```

I have never seen the $ character used this way. My guess is that there's probably no difference at all.

Comment: Why we put or copy interrupt "1eh" in place of volume name (7c2bh)

Comment: @ShankarTiwariji You are looking at the source of an ancient DOS (version 1.25). The volume label only became part of the bootsector starting with DOS v4, so the space at 7C2Bh is unoccupied (or at least it's ok to be overwritten). But even if a volume label were present at 7C2Bh, it would not matter since the bootsector program itself will not be using the volume label anyway.